# Como poner restricciones dentro de un complexType en XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Tengo este codigo en xsd:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="smartphones">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="movil" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="so"/>

                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:length value="20"/>
                    </xs:restriction>

              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="v_so"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="dimensions"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="pes"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="resolucio"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="processador"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="memoria"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="preu"/>
            </xs:sequence>
             </xs:complexContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Quiero poner una restriccion "so" de màximo 40 caracteres pero el validador me da error. (The Element Type "xs:complexType" Must Be Terminated By The Matching End-tag "").

Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes modelar tu elemento asi:

```
      <xs:element name="so">
           <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
            </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
```

Usa el elemento `maxLength` en lugar de `length`, este último exige que tenga una longitud de exactamente 20.

Te recomiendo usar un editor de XML que te ayude a construir el esquema, como [OxygenXML](https://www.oxygenxml.com/) o [Altova XMLSpy](https://www.altova.com/xmlspy-xml-editor). Una opcion gratuita es [XMLPad](http://xmlpad-mobile.com/#WmHelp)

Answer (score 0):

Le estás diciendo que tenga un tamaño de 20 caracteres, deberías decirle un valor mínimo y otro máximo `<xs:element name="so"> <xs:simpleType> <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> <xs:minLength value="1"/> <xs:maxLength value="40"/> </xs:restriction> </xs:simpleType> </xs:element>`